# Can't get router to properly redirect traffic on port 80

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I was having trouble with my router (Linksys AC1350) recently, so i performed a factory reset by holding in the recessed button on the back.

Ever since, the url that was redirecting to my local webserver is now redirecting to my router's settings login page, just like it does when i navigate directly to 192.168.1.1 in a browser. Navigating directly to my server's local IP address gets the proper webpage displayed, *as does navigating to my public IP*. It is only when accessing my network via url that the incorrect redirect happens.

I have restored all of my previous port forwarding settings (22, 80, 110, 143, 587, 993, 995) and other services (SSH, smtp) seem to be working fine regardless of whether i'm connecting via local IP, public IP, or url.

I have remote administration turned off so perhaps this isn't a giant security problem, but it is a problem that my website - a mirror of the resume i've been sending around - is no longer visible. I'm going to look like a giant noob if anybody's looking to hire me and my personal url resolves to a 404'd router UI.

I normally would dig around until i find an answer or fix it myself, but i'm feeling urgent, as i never know when or if a prospective employer may be trying to view my webpage. Forgive me if this has been beaten to death already, but no copies were apparent in some related searches.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: 0) Have you confirmed this is a problem from *outside* your LAN? 1) You say you get to the correct page if you navigate to your public IP. Is that the case from inside your LAN, outside of it, or both? 2) Is your public IP returned when you ping the hostname portion of your URL from outside your LAN? What if you ping it from inside your LAN? 3) Does your webserver inspect the hostname specified in your URL? If so, is it looking for the correct hostname?

Comment: I had tried clearing browser cache and connecting from outside my network (phone's data connection). Behavior was consistent for different checks whether inside or outside of the network. Pinging was how I confirmed my public ip hadn't changed when I reset the router, but I only did that from within the network. The hostname is actually different locally, and I've just been using the router to redirect traffic to individual machines based on the port being called. Lighttpd is set up to answer any request on port 80 with my document root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm an idiot. After digging around in the settings some more and realizing that my browser cache wasn't the only thing that probably should be cleared, I power cycled the router. Sometimes I forget that turning it off and back on can actually be a valid fix.